# Send part of a file through Multipart Requests: Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, multipart

I intend to send a large file through Multipart request of Retrofit. Now, for this, I have decided to divide the file into chunks of byte arrays and some other meta info. to identify what part has reached and what hasn't.

I have seen examples using Retrofit's Multipart request to send a complete File.

How can I send a byte array as a *part* of a Multipart request instead of a File?

Comment: https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service go for this library ,it manages large files automatically and returns the remaining time and bytes uploaded to server

Comment: you can do that by writing a custom `RequestBody` class which takes, for example, `MediaType contentType, File file, int startOffset, int length)` in its constructor - the two `int` params will be used when implementing `writeTo` method

Comment: @pskink : Any idea, what might be the appropriate content type for the byte array? This is originally an encrypted file I am breaking into chunks

Comment: treat it as a normal encrypted file - i dont think there is "encrypted chunked file" content type...

Comment: @pskink : Yes, but what should I put in as a content type string in the request? (Ex: application/json)

Comment: and what would you pass if you wanted to upload the whole file? how would you create `RequestBody` object?